# Rdd to json in spark and scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, playframework-2.0

I take a Json file with spark/scala and i save it in a rdd.

```
  val dataFile = "resources/tweet-json/hello.json"
  lazy val rdd = SparkCommons.sqlContext.read.format("json").load(dataFile)
```

After querying rdd, i want to generate again a Json output file (that i will send with a get Http request). How can i convert this rdd in json?

```
[
{
    "label": [
        "fattacq_an_eser_facq",
        "eu_tot_doc",
        "fattacq_prot_facq",
        "id_sogg",
        "eu_tot_man"
    ],
    "values": [
        {
            "label": "Prima Fattura 2016",
            "values": [
                2016,
                956.48,
                691,
                44633,
                956.48
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Seconda Fattura 2016",
            "values": [
                2016,
                190,
                982,
                38127,
                190
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Terza Fattura 2016",
            "values": [
                2016,
                140.3,
                1088,
                59381,
                140.3
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Quarta Fattura 2016",
            "values": [
                2016,
                488,
                1091,
                59382,
                488
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Quinta Fattura 2016",
            "values": [
                2016,
                11365.95,
                1154,
                57526,
                11365.95
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Sesta Fattura 2016",
            "values": [
                2016,
                44440.01,
                1276,
                5555,
                44440.01
            ]
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: P.s.: I use Play Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the write function to write out the Json
Example:

```
dfTobeSaved.write.format("json").save("/root/data.json")
```

I think this should work fine !

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i need to send this file with http request. How can i make it?

Comment: After quering i save the rdd in json format and then, how can i send this file as an Http answer with GET method?

Comment: For that you can use Akka-http for sending it.. You can take a look here for more http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/http/client-side/request-level.html Thanks and do the upvote so that others can find the answer easily

Comment: Oh i just saw that you are using Play also , so then you would not require akka http you can easily do it in play

Comment: How can i make it in play? How can i response with a json file in play?