# Convert RDD[Map[String, String]] to Spark dataframe

Tags: python, json, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm trying to convert a `val rec: RDD[Map[String, String]]` into a Spark dataframe.

But when I execute:

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rec, classOf[Map[String, String]])

df.write.json("/tmp/file.json")
```

The file json is full of empty objects:

```
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
```

I'm converting it to json just because I want save the `rec` val and reuse it later with SQLContext object in python.

So the question is how to save my `RDD[HashMap[String, String]]` created in Scala and reuse later in Python?

**UPDATE**

`rec` val contains

```
Map(Param_timestamp -> 2017-03-28T02:00:02.887, Param_querytype -> listing, Param_slug -> /salute-beauty-fitness/bellezza-cura-del-corpo/cosmesi/makeup, Param_br -> CAUDALIE)
```

`df.show()` returns:

```
++
||
++
||
... all the 20 lines are the alike "||"
||
++
only showing top 20 rows
```

Comment: What is the content of `rec` ? And what is the output of `df.show()` ?

Comment: @L.CWI Just updated my question

Comment: What about using `StructType(
    StructField("timeStamp", StringType, false) ::
    StructField("querytype", StringType, false) ::
    StructField("slug", StringType, false):: StructField("br", StringType, false) :: Nil)` inside your createDataframe? (I don't know much about scala, but somehhow you need to specify the schema when creating your dataframe, and since it's empty I would think the wrong schema is used here)

Comment: But I have an hashmap, the keys in the hashmap should be the name of the fields and all the values are String, right?

Comment: I have a dynamic number of fields that will be generated at run time, so the StructType should be determined dynamically.

Comment: What is the source of that data? If is a Json file, you can use inferschema and read it as a DataFrame/Dataset.

Comment: @Joss I tried but how to export a the rdd in a json file?

Comment: Could you give a sample of a RDD to convert to a dataframe so that I can test  on my end?

Comment: @freedev like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758105/convert-rdd-to-json-object, or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40056980/rdd-to-json-in-spark-and-scala. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you master your schema, you can recreate it through the use of StructField and StructType, the [doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema) explains it pretty well I believe. As for scala, I'm not exactly familiar with it but a small example in Java can perhaps help (I'll convert it to Scala later when I have more time):

```
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(
            new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local[*]"));
    jsc.setLogLevel("ERROR");
    System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\Temp\\tt\\Tools");

    List<Tuple2<String, String>> test = new ArrayList<Tuple2<String, String>>();
    Tuple2<String, String> tt = new Tuple2<String, String>("key", "val1");
    test.add(tt);
    tt = new Tuple2<String, String>("key", "val2");
    test.add(tt);
    tt = new Tuple2<String, String>("key2", "val");
    test.add(tt);

    JavaPairRDD<String, String> testRDD = jsc.parallelizePairs(test);

    System.out.println(testRDD.first());

    SparkContext sc = JavaSparkContext.toSparkContext(jsc);
    SparkSession ss = new SparkSession(sc);
    StructField[] fields = {
            DataTypes.createStructField("key", DataTypes.StringType, false),
            DataTypes.createStructField("val", DataTypes.StringType, false) };
    StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);
    JavaRDD<Row> testRowRDD = testRDD.map(line -> RowFactory.create(line._1, line._2));
    Dataset<Row> myDF = ss.createDataFrame(testRowRDD, schema);
    myDF.show();

    myDF.write().json("test.json");

    jsc.close();
```

The output is several Json files, containing each one line like this:

```
{"key":"key2","val":"val"}
```